# Run a target from a custom target in CMake

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I have the following file structure:

```
├── Generator/
│   ├── output/
│   └── script.py
│
└── FinalProgram/
    ├── build/
    ├── src/
    │   └── main.cpp
    ├── include/
    │   └── MyClass.h
    └── CMakeLists.txt
```

The `Generator/script.py` file is a script that generates c++ files in the `Generator/output` folder. That script can be launched with two different arguments (SimA and SimB), each one generating a different set of files.

On the other hand, the `FinalProgram` needs to use that set of generated files, so every time I want to compile the `FinalProgram` with the `SimA` set of files, I have to

```
cd Generator 
./script.py SimA
cp output/*.cpp ../FinalProgram/src
cp output/*.h   ../FinalProgram/include
cd ../FinalProgram/build && cmake ..
make
```

What I want is to be able to type

```
make SimA
```

Or

```
make SimB
```

So everything happens automatically. In both cases **the executable must be the same**, so obviously I cannot have two different `add_executable` blocks. I guess I should create two `add_custom_target` blocks, one for each possible value, do all the work there and finally call the target that compiles everything. Hence, the real question is, how can I run another target from within an `add_custom_target` block? Of course, I guess I could use

```
COMMAND make
```

But that... that makes me cry. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: I'm a little confused at what your asking. Why can you just use add_custom_command to set the file level dependencies and then add a add_custom_target and use http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_dependencies.html for top level targets?

Comment: To clarify, you should list all your (probably simplified) inputs, outputs, and dependencies, and you'll probably be able to write the script from just that.

Comment: I've rephrased the entire question, maybe it's a little bit more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

As MadScienceDreams mentioned, you can use `add_custom_command` to generate the c++ file, then you can use generated file in `add_executable` command.

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../Generator/output/SimA.cpp
                   COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} script.py SimA
                   DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../Generator/script.py
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../Generator)

set_property(SOURCE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../Generator/output/SimA.cpp PROPERTY GENERATED TRUE)

add_executable(SimA ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../Generator/output/SimA.cpp ...)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../Generator/output/SimB.cpp
                   COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} script.py SimB
                   DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../Generator/script.py
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../Generator)

set_property(SOURCE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../Generator/output/SimB.cpp PROPERTY GENERATED TRUE)

add_executable(SimB ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../Generator/output/SimB.cpp ...)
```

For more information see

- http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html
- http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_sf/GENERATED.html

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself properly. Precisely having two different `add_executable` blocks is something I do not want, because the executable must be the same. At one given time it's compiled with one set or another. That's why I need to be able to call the target that actually compiles the executable from the custom target.